# how to save response with “ContentType= {image/jpeg}” as image C#?

Tags: c#, image, console, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph API to fetch the user profile image from Azure Active Directory.

See example:

[image]

I am utilizing this API call using C# console app. I am having following code.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer","MY ACCESS TOKEN");
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value");
var test = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Now, here the Content-Type of the response is `{image/jpeg}`.

The data which I am getting is looking like in the property **`Result`** from following image.

[image]

When I try to save this image on my local drive using following code:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\image.bmp", Convert.FromBase64String(test.Result));
```

It gives me error:

> {System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it
>   contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or
>   an illegal character among the padding characters.     at
>   System.Convert.FromBase64_ComputeResultLength(Char* inputPtr, Int32
>   inputLength)    at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr,
>   Int32 inputLength)    at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
>   at
>   Microsoft_Graph_Mail_Console_App.MailClient.d__c.MoveNext()
>   in d:\Source\MailClient.cs:line 125}

I understand this error, because the result is not convertible to **byte[]**.

So, I want to know that, Can I directly use the data from `Result` property to create and save image on my local system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of images, the content of the response is a byte stream not a string.
So, you just have to read the response steam and copy it to an output stream. For example:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value");
using (Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\image.jpg", FileMode.Create))
    {
        // in dotnet 4.5
        await source.CopyToAsync(fs);
    }
}
```

If you are, in `dotnet 4.0`, use `source.CopyTo(fs)` instead of its async couterpart.